# What could be the reason of failing of mini-dump generation but successful generation of complete Windows memory dump?

Tags: windows, crash-dumps

I was testing for Windows SVVP (server virtualization validation program) test and I observe unexpected behavior. When I put 80 Gigs of storage for a 60 cores system, I am able to get the "Complete" memory dump. However, with same configuration, the mini-dump stucks at 0%.

I search many documents including from MSDN, but could able to find a very good reason for this behavior. What is a possible reason for such behavior?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that a complete dump simply dumps all mapped memory regions.  The minidump tries to find the "interesting" bits, so it's walking stacks and following key pointers.  Perhaps there's corruption causing a cycle, so the dumper gets stuck trying to follow pointers forever.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Could you please share any links where the complete events flow of these dump types - Minidump, kernel dump, and complete dump, are described. When I search on the web I found only the difference between these dump types and nothing about the flow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: AFAIK, interesting memory is only considered max. 2 pointers away, so this should not result in an endless loop.